# loading Viewer.ToolKit Extension

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am currently going through the github codes of Level-Filtering demo provided in https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=5a7185a92a0a7aeb152725d5 
I would like to know how Viewer.Toolkit is imported to this js-file, and how could i use it in my app.
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.LevelFilter

Answer (score 0):

It's an ES6 module, please document yourself about [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

Comment: I did import the file as given in the example but the problem I am currently facing is because 'Viewer.Toolkit' is not present in our project. How can I get that file in my project? Do I copy it directly or there is any other way to get it, as like extension?

Comment: just copy, this code is not part of the API, it's a sample, like any other extensions from forge-rcdb